# Entropy Maximizers / Techniques

Tags: statistics, entropy

I have no background on statistics, and am trying to learn the basics. In particular, I’m trying to prove the following:

Among all continuous functions on $(0,\infty)$ with mean $1$, prove that the entropy maximizer $f$ has entropy $H(f) := \int_0^\infty -f(x) \operatorname{log}(f(x)) dx$ being $1$.

#### Questions

1. What are some techniques worth paying attention to when proving entropy maximizers? Even in the easiest example over a finite set with volume $1$, I had to use the inequality $log(X) \leq X-1$, which seems like a clever trick to me, i.e. it would have taken me more than a half hour to figure out if I’ve never seen it before.
2. Note that the proof ask for the maximized among all *continuous* distributions. Can one use variational methods for this type of problems still?
3. If I change $log$ to other functions in the definition of entropy and ask for maximizers, are there still statistical interpretations?

Comment: Do you know about Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: Yes, but only for finite dimensional case. Even if it works directly here for smooth distributions, we still need some arguments for continuous ones.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P(f):=\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\,dx$ and $E(f):=\int_0^{\infty}xf(x)\,dx$. Then the problem can be formally stated as follows
\begin{align}
\min_f &-H(f) \\
\text{s.t.}&\quad f\ge 0, \\
&\quad  P(f)=1, \\
&\quad  E(f)=1.
\end{align}
The corresponding [Lagrangian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) (we drop the non-negativity constraint for a moment) is
$$
L(f,\lambda)=-H(f)+\lambda_1(P(f)-1)+\lambda_2(E(f)-1).
$$
Taking the [functional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) of $L$ w.r.t. $f$ one gets (for $x\ge 0$)
$$
1+\ln f(x) +\lambda_1+\lambda_2x =0,
$$
which implies that
$$
f^{*}(x)=e^{-1-\lambda_1-\lambda_2x}1_{[0,\infty)}(x).
$$
Note that the optimal $f^*\ge 0$. The Lagrange multipliers $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ can be found by solving $P(f^*)=1$ and $E(f^*)=1$. Consequently, the required density is
$$
f^{*}(x)=e^{-x}1_{[0,\infty)}(x) \quad\text{and}\quad H(f^{*})=\int_0^{\infty}xe^{-x}\,dx=1.
$$

Comment: How do we take care of nonsmooth functions?